# Convergence Distribution and Probability

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, convergence

Suppose that $|X_n - Y_n|$ converges in probability to 0, and that $X_n$ converges in distribution to X. Show that $Y_n$ converges in distribution to X.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for editing your post, can you include what you tried as well?

Answer (score 1):

Goal: show $P(Y_n \le t) \to P(X \le t)$ [for $t$ at which $F_X(t):=P(X \le t)$ is continuous].

Hints:

- $P(Y_n \le t) = P(Y_n \le t, |X_n - Y_n| > \epsilon) + P(Y_n \le t, |X_n - Y_n| \le \epsilon)$.
- $P(Y_n \le t, |X_n - Y_n| > \epsilon) \le P(|X_n - Y_n| > \epsilon)$. What does the right-hand side converge to?
- $P(Y_n \le t, |X_n - Y_n| \le \epsilon) \le P(X_n \le t + \epsilon)$. What does the right-hand side converge to?
- Use the assumption that $F_X(t)$ is continuous at $t$.